# Regex: Case insensitive search performance, /i vs enumeration

Tags: regex, performance

In regard to performance of regex pattern matching with case insensitivity, which is more optimal: using /i or enumerating both upper and lower case characters?

For example, let's say I want to search for alpha-numeric strings. I can use either of these regexes: `/[a-z0-9]+/i` or `/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/`. Is either one more performant?

Can this be evaluated in a general case, or is the specific engine necessary?

Comment: How about running a benchmark?

Comment: I imagine it would be the same speed in many regex engines. optimizing, e.g. `/[a-z]/i` to `/[a-zA-Z]/` is very easy, and probably less work than implementing a separate case insensitive mode anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this target sample `asd09PfdDwr9ePfdswPkduYYY9`
the [benchmark](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b2.jpg) is

```
Regex1:   [a-zA-Z0-9]+
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.33 s,   325.36 ms,   325359 µs
Matches per sec:   153,676


Regex2:   [a-z0-9]+
Options:  < i >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   1
Elapsed Time:    0.36 s,   360.95 ms,   360947 µs
Matches per sec:   138,524
```

Comment: Interesting! Any idea why the former is significantly faster?

Comment: @MatthewWoo - Yes, I would say that the extra step of lowercasing then comparison check for `[a-z]` is slower than the `[a-z]` then `[A-Z]` comparisons, since the engine already knows what to check for and doesn't have to auto-convert each character just to check it.